# Looking for feedback on an implementation of a single use token for login

Tags: authentication, jwt, token

An integration for the app I'm working on requires that a user be logged in via a redirect. So the plan is to have a single use token as url param, then once they get redirected and the token is verified I will create a session for them with cookies. Unfortunately putting the token in the headers is not an option here. I was thinking of ways to accomplish this without having to make a new table for either whitelisting or blacklisting tokens, and came up with this:

Create a token who's payload includes an expiration time, the users id, and the users last sign in datetime. Then encode that token with a secret.

Then to validate the token after the redirect, it first gets decoded using the secret. Then the expiration time is checked. Lastly, I get the user's last sign in datetime from the database, and check that it matches the one in the token payload. If all checks pass, then the user is signed in, and a session cookie is set for them.

Mainly I'm looking for feedback about security. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to look at either OpenID Connect (which is based on OAuth) and ID tokens.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at SAML.